# Make File Upload Field Optional on Contact Form

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have a basic HTML/PHP web form. Everything works fine when I fill out all fields, except I want to make the file upload optional, not required. I have taken "required" off of the form html for the upload. I checked my handler.php and it does not say that field is required. I checked the formhandler.php and it says that attachments are null. I have looked through similar questions, but any of the more complex solutions I am probably implementing incorrectly. I've expended my knowledge of php looking for a solution. What am I missing?

Here is the html of the form:

```
<div class="row pb6">
                <div class="col-md-6  offset-md-3">
                    <form role="form" method="post" id="reused_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email"> Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tel"> Phone: </label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" maxlength="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name"> Message:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="We want to hear all about your performance! Also, please include the date you need the music." maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="file">File Upload (optional)</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Post It! &rarr;</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "> <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3> </div>
                    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; "><h3>Error</h3>We are very sorry. There was an error sending your form. Email us and we will send you a free demo.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the handler.php:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )

 */
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email','tel'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);


if($_FILES['image']){ $pp->attachFiles(['image']); }


$pp->sendEmailTo('email'); //

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

after code edit: 
1)Chrome and Firefox will send form, Safari will not. 
2)All browsers show a perpetual "Sending" message, and do not show a success or failure message for the form. 
3) Forms send WITH attachments will not send the form with attachment to email, only the form alone.

Comment: Yes, you needed to click `{}` and not `""` to format the PHP

Comment: Well you probably should not call `$pp->attachFiles(['image']);` if there isn’t an actual image.

Comment: if($_FILES['image']){  $pp->attachFiles(['image']);  }

Comment: Sanjay Kumar, thank you, I replaced line 22 of the php with your code (between the last validator line and the sendEmailTo line), it did not work. Should I be placing this somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to attach the image whether it exists or not with `$pp->attachFiles(['image']);`. You should first check if it does indeed exists and only attach it if it does like so:

```
if($_FILES['image']){ 
$pp->attachFiles(['image']); 
}
```

Comment: I've used your code to replace the line in my original. The form will still not send without a file attached. Should I put the new line somewhere else? Thank you.

Comment: you could also try this: `if(isset_file($_FILES[ 'image']){$pp->attachFiles(['image']); 
}`

Comment: No error given, just a perpetual "sending" message, but the form never completes to either a success or error message.

Comment: Have tried the isset version as well, same result. I got an error that I needed to close parentheses, which I did before the {$pp ... part. Still getting a "sending" message with no conclusion both with and without the added parentheses.

Comment: Odd. In my second suggestion I made an error (forgot to close `(`, it should be         `if(isset_file($_FILES[ 'image'])){$pp->attachFiles(['image']); }`

Comment: After some changes and reloads: the original answer you gives works, but a) only in Chrome or Firefox: Safariwill not send the email; and b) the website doesn't notify that the form was successful: it shows the perpetual "sending" message. So thank you for your help in getting so far; am I doing anything else incorrect that could be causing these followup issues?

Comment: Please update your original question's code to what you have now so we can have a look at your current code.

Comment: Additional info: now attachments will not deliver from any browser, though, I don't think I changed anything but will continue tests.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see anything wrong with your code.